# How do I copy the contents of a bytearray to a list (Python)?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x, arrays

I have a dictionary which I convert to a bytearray, and since bytearrays are immutable (can't be modified) I try to make a list equal to each index in the bytearray.

```
a = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
b = bytearray(str(a), 'ASCII')
c = []

for i in b:
    c[i] = b[i]     # Error on this line

print(str(c))
```

The problem is it keeps printing `IndexError: bytearray index out of range`.
How and why is the bytearray out of range?

Comment: Joran Beasley's answer explains why you get this exception. But if you fix that (e.g., with `for index, value in enumerate(b): c[index] = value`), you're just going to get an `IndexError` on the `list`. If you have an empty list, you can't just set `c[0]`, because there is no `c[0]` to set. You need to use `append` (or come up with some other solution, like pre-allocating the list `c = [None for _ in b]`—but if you knew how to do that, you'd know this whole question was unnecessary).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I correctly understood your question, you can simply use `c = list(b)`:

```
a = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
b = bytearray(str(a), 'ASCII')
c = list(b)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[123, 49, 58, 32, 39, 97, 39, 44, 
 32, 50, 58, 32, 39, 98, 39, 44, 
 32, 51, 58, 32, 39, 99, 39, 125]
```

In order to understand why you get this error, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843641/how-do-i-copy-the-contents-of-a-bytearray-to-a-list-python/16843708#16843708).

Comment: This is the answer to what the OP is trying to do; Joran Beasley's is the answer to what's wrong with how the OP did it. +1 to both.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and helpful reply. I wasn't aware of the list function. Will mark as answer in a few minutes.

Comment: @Joseph Webber: Glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 4):

`i` is the **value** in `b` **not the index**

```
b = [1,5,20]
for i in b:
   print i #prints 1,then 5 , then 20
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code:

```
a = {1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c'}
b = bytearray(str(a), 'ASCII')
c = []

for i in b:
    c.append(i)
```

or, better still, you can use the byte array directly with the `list` constructor and forgo the loop:

```
c=list(b)
```

or, skip the byte array and use a list comprehension:

```
c= [ord(ch) for ch in str(a)]
```

In all these cases, you get the list of ASCII ordinals if that is your goal:

```
[123, 49, 58, 32, 39, 97, 39, 44, 32, 50, 58, 32, 39, 98, 39, 44, 32, 51, 58, 32, 39, 99, 39, 125]
```